# ASP C# Querying DayOfWeek in INT form , how to break it down to Days?

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, enums

Alright , I had this enum

```
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    [EnumMember]
    Monday = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Tuesday = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    Wednesday = 4,
    [EnumMember]
    Thursday = 8,
    [EnumMember]
    Friday = 16,
    [EnumMember]
    Saturday = 32,
    [EnumMember]
    Sunday = 64
}
```

This enum is stored into the DB as INT . They are being inserted through checkbox , so for example if I check Monday and Tuesday , they will be stored as 3 (1+2) according to their sum total value .

Now I would like to query back this data , and with only 3 as the output , how can I convert it back to day , Monday and Tuesday .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

You need to decorate your enum with the [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) in order to be able to set this correctly.

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    [EnumMember]
    Monday = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Tuesday = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    Wednesday = 4,
    [EnumMember]
    Thursday = 8,
    [EnumMember]
    Friday = 16,
    [EnumMember]
    Saturday = 32,
    [EnumMember]
    Sunday = 64
}
```

Then, setting 3 would mean that both `Monday` and `Tuesday` were selected.

This will output `Monday, Tuesday`:

```
Console.WriteLine(((DaysOfWeek)3).ToString());
```

Comment: Hold on , any other ways rather than applying the flag property ? Because this flag property might break other module in the project , so I'm looking for an alternative .

Comment: @user777310 - a `Flags` enum is the classic way to do this. The only other alternative I see is to specify each and every day combination as a specific enum value (`MondayTuesday = 3` etc...) - not very appealing at all. Without knowing what you think may break, it is very difficult to recommend an alternative.